# Failed to update static column in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cql3, cqlsh, nosql

I have strange problem with Cassandra (version 2.2.3) database and using static columns when write some proof of concept for simple application with send money functionality.

My table is:

```
CREATE TABLE transactions (
profile text,
timestamp timestamp,
amount text,
balance text,
lock int static,
PRIMARY KEY (profile, timestamp)) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (timestamp ASC);
```

First step I add new record

```
INSERT INTO transactions (profile, timestamp, amount) VALUES ( 'test_profile', '2015-11-05 15:20:01+0000', '10USD');
```

Then I want to 'lock' current user transaction to do some action with his balance. I try to execute this request:

```
UPDATE transactions SET lock = 1 WHERE profile = 'test_profile' IF lock = null;
```

But as result in cqlsh I see

```
     [applied]
-----------
     False
```

I don't understand why 'False', because current data for profile is:

```
 profile      | timestamp                | lock | amount | balance
--------------+--------------------------+------+--------+---------
 test_profile | 2015-11-05 15:20:01+0000 | null |  10USD |    null
```

Any idea what I do wrong?

**UPDATE**

After read Nenad Bozic answer I modify my example to clarify why I need condition in update. Full code sample

```
CREATE TABLE transactions (
    profile text,
    timestamp timestamp,
    amount text,
    balance text,
    lock int static,
    balances map<text,text> static,
    PRIMARY KEY (profile, timestamp)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (timestamp ASC);
INSERT INTO transactions (profile, timestamp, amount) VALUES ( 'test_profile', '2015-11-05 15:20:01+0000', '1USD');
INSERT INTO transactions (profile, lock) VALUES ('test_profile', 1) IF NOT EXISTS;
BEGIN BATCH
        UPDATE transactions SET balances={'USD':'1USD'} WHERE profile='test_profile';
        UPDATE transactions SET balance='1USD' WHERE profile='test_profile' AND timestamp='2015-11-05 15:20:01+0000';
        DELETE lock FROM transactions WHERE profile='test_profile';
APPLY BATCH;
```

And if I try get lock again I get

```
INSERT INTO transactions (profile, lock) VALUES ('test_profile', 1) IF NOT EXISTS;

 [applied] | profile      | timestamp | balances        | lock | amount | balance
-----------+--------------+-----------+-----------------+------+--------+---------
     False | test_profile |      null | {'USD': '1USD'} | null |   null |    null
```

Comment: Could be the same issue as https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10532

Comment: I test in `cassandra 3.0.0-rc2` and It works... But not work in other versions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you `INSERT` you do not insert `lock` field which means this field does not exist. Null representation in CQLSH or DevCenter is only synthetic sugar to make results looks like tabular data but in reality it has dynamic key values and `lock` is not present in that map of key values. It is useful to look [thrift representation](http://www.planetcassandra.org/making-the-change-from-thrift-to-cql/) of data even though it is not used anymore to get sense how it is stored to disk.

So when `UPDATE` is fired it is expecting column to be present to updated it. In your case `lock` column is not even present so it cannot update it. This [thread](http://grokbase.com/t/cassandra/user/14bhhpfwpw/if-not-exists-on-update-statements) on difference between `INSERT` and `UPDATE` is also good read.

You have two solutions to make this work:

**Insert null explicitly**

You can add `lock` to your insert statement and set it to null (which is different in Cassandra than excluding it from insert because this way it will get null value and when you exclude it this column would not exist in

```
INSERT INTO transactions (profile, timestamp, amount, lock) 
VALUES ( 'test_profile', '2015-11-05 15:20:01+0000', '10USD', null);
```

**Use insert on second statement**

Since you are inserting on second statement `lock` for first time instead of updating existing value and since it is static column for that partition you can use `INSERT IF NOT EXISTS` instead of `UPDATE IF` LWT way of doing it (lock would not exist so this will pass first time and fail all other times since lock will have value):

```
INSERT INTO transactions (profile, lock) 
VALUES ('test_profile', 1) IF NOT EXISTS;
```

Comment: Because DELETE in Cassandra is not physical delete, it is logical delete (column value is marked with tombstone for deletion on next compaction) - http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.0/cql/cql_using/use_delete.html

Comment: I suggest to use values here (locked = 1, not locked = 0 or boolean or whatever) and switch value based on that. In first insert set it on 0 and then do conditional UPDATE with IF lock = 0 etc. Also pay attention that Batch is only all or nothing operation but it cannot guarantee order of statements.

Comment: Yes I know about all or nothing. Now I need to think about how setup default static value when first write is performed and for performance without any additional read before write, but I thin it is a different problem.

I know about delete, but for my opinion now INSEER with IF NOT EXISTS work strange